# I'm having trouble with the code include below. I keep receiving errors in the console

Tags: jquery, html, copy, paste

```js
$(".hexData").on("click", function() {
  var inputEle = $("<input>");
  $("body").append(inputEle);
  inputEle.val($(element).text()).select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  inputEle.remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="field hexData"></div>
<div class="button">
  <button class="bttnColor">Copy</button>
</div>
```

I have this function that doesn't seem to work with the class hexData in div.
This is what I receive in the console:

```
index.html?url=:125 Uncaught ReferenceError: element is not defined
at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (index.html?url=:125)
at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3)
at HTMLDivElement.q.handle (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3)
(anonymous) @ index.html?url=:125
dispatch @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3
q.handle @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3
```

My goal is to copy text in the class field hexData div using jQuery on.('click' event.

Comment: `$(element).text()` element is not defined

Comment: how can I correct this?

Comment: define `element`

Comment: somewhat new at coding here. can you display the function with element defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you appear to want is :

```
$('button.bttnColor').on("click", function() {
    var inputEle = $("<input />")
        .appendTo("body")
        .val($('.hexData').text())
        .select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    inputEle.remove();
});
```

You will end up with a copy of text from the `.hexData` div on the Operating System's clipboard.

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/w0k0taxa/)**